# Unable to Deploy Smart-contract to Ropsten from Truffle using Infura

Tags: ropsten, infura, rinkeby

I want to deploy my smart-contract on ropsten or rinkeby network from Truffle using Infura API, but face difficulty in deploying on any network.
I am using windows and my contract works well on ganache and also deployed ropsten and rinkeby usin Remix. Configure my **truffle-configure.js** for these network still its not working.

[image]
[image: here it stop and not start deploying to ropsten network]

Comment: Please share your actual code and output, not screenshots of them. Screenshots are not searchable/copy-pastable/accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Missing "/v3". Try - "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/"+infura_apikey